# Answering old questions

Tags: discussion

Does it make sense to answer old questions in case other people stumble across them? For instance: [Custom Post Type Archives with 0 Posts Redirects as 404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11607/custom-post-type-archives-with-0-posts-redirects-as-404) (fixed in 3.2). I always figure you never know where people are looking for information :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Absolutely!**

1. You spread the good and up to date knowledge around.
2. You help reduce the nasty *unanswered* pile.
3. You get rep and possibly nifty Revival or Necromancer badge.

Comment: Can't say more than that. Also: It's often surprising what good Qs come up from there.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I'm trying to stop lurking so much and actually do something! Now, if only people would actually come back to accept some answers... :)

Comment: Don't worry about "accept" @helenhousandi - Q&A is most important for all the readers who *didn't* ask the question; even if the original asker never returns, the effort you put in may well be of great value to many.

Answer (score 3):

Also don't forget the Google.
Old Q/A's certainly show up in long tail searches.